# Windows analog to UNIX atoh() function

Tags: windows, mfc

Is there in Windows API or in MFC any analog to `atoh()` function?

`atoh()` converts a string containing a hexadecimal number into an unsigned number like

```
unsigned x = atoh("A");
```

and x = 10 after the operation.

In Windows I have a CString, containing "A". How can I convert it to int?

Comment: Just FYI - atoh is not even close to being a standard library call on UNIX and the strto*l library calls are meant to replace the ato* library calls in general now.

Comment: you're right ). Sorry, UNIX also has strtol().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long x = strtoul("A", (char **) NULL, 16);
// x will be 10 decimal
```

Comment: This is signed, not unsigned. Sigh. I'm getting petty in the hunt for rep points. :|

Comment: @unwind, that's true... just change it to strtoul for him :)

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned long ten = strtoul("a", NULL, 16);` should handle it, if you can get a plain old `char *`-representation out of the CString. The accepted solution using `strtoul()` does a signed conversion.

Comment: For compatibility with CString, which can be either based on char or wchar_t, #include <tchar.h> and use _tcstoul.